# Getting Null Pointer Exception on setAdapter spinner

Tags: android

I dont know why i am getting null pointer exception , my code is seem to be simple , but dont know why , here is my code ,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_macro_requirement);
        text_gaol=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.macro_goal_calories_calculated);
        txtview_percent_macro_protein=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.macro_protein_percentage_calculated);
        txtview_percent_maccro_fats=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.macro_fat_percentage_calculated);
        txtview_percent_maccro_carbs=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.macro_carb_percentage_calculated);
        txt_macro_protein_percentage_manual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.macro_protein_percentage_manual);
        txt_macro_fats_percentage_manual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.macro_fat_percentage_manual);
        txt_macro_carbs_percentage_manual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.macro_carb_percentage_manual);

        Spinner goal_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.macro_goal_spinner);
        List<String> setactivity = new ArrayList<String>();
        setactivity.add("Choose your Goal");
        setactivity.add("Gain Weight");
        setactivity.add("Loss Weight");
        setactivity.add("Maintain Weight");
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, setactivity);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        goal_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Getting NullPointerException on above line .

Here is my Layout for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/macro"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5.0dip" >

        <View
            android:id="@id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2.0dip"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text_current_playback_title"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/label_tdee"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_result"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/result_color" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=" "
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/label_goal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@id/macro_goal_spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/macro_goal_section_calculated"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5.0dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/label_goal_calories"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/macro_goal_calories_calculated"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/result_color" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5.0dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_nutrtional_plan"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#635fd0"
                android:padding="5.0dip"
                android:text="@string/label_choose_nutrition_plan"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <View
                android:id="@id/view1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2.0dip"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/text_current_playback_title"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_back_profile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#635fd0"
            android:padding="5.0dip"
            android:text="Back To Profile"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Everything looks ok as far as ..

Comment: sorry, my bad .:( ....Error logs will be helpful if provided

Comment: please post the layout "fragment_macro_requirement.xml"

Comment: Can you please make changes in my code , on which line ..Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Change `android:id="@id/macro_goal_spinner"` to `android:id="@+id/macro_goal_spinner"`. Add + in the id in your views

Comment: Thanks by adding + in my layout its work ,

Answer (score 0):

**Remove setactivity and add your arraylist** there ,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, setactivity);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, YOURARRAYLISTOBJECT);
```

**YOURARRAYLISTOBJECT is from where you get data in spinner.**